# Is it possible to place an anchor in an HTML5 placeholder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(i.e., a link inside a `<textarea>` that isn't shown once the textarea is active or has text in it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the W3C specs on the `placeholder` attribute says nothing about non-plaintext values.

Try this jQuery plugin instead, which positions `<label>` elements on top of `<input>` elements and make them act like placeholders: http://fuelyourcoding.com/in-field-labels/

(This came out in a Google search, I am not associated with the plugin, plugin author or the website in any way)

Answer (score 1):

A [textarea](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-TEXTAREA) element contains PCDATA, it can't contain any markup or other elements.